# setting xlim and ylim while using matplotlib (something strange)

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
# the first plot DOES NOT set the xlim and ylim properly 
import numpy as np
import pylab as p

x = np.linspace(0.0,5.0,20)
slope = 1.0 
intercept = 3.0 
y = slope*x + intercept
p.set_xlim = ([0.0,10.0])
p.set_ylim = ([0.0,10.0])
p.plot(x,y)
p.show()
p.clf()

def xyplot():
    slope = 1.0
    intercept = 3.0
    x = np.linspace(0.0,5.0,20)
    y = slope*x + intercept 
    p.xlim([0.0,10.0])
    p.ylim([0.0,10.0])
    p.plot(x,y)
    p.show()

# if I place the same exact code a a function, the xlim and ylim
# do what I want ...

xyplot()
```

Comment: `pylab.set_xlim` does not exist

Comment: Try calling them after you call `.plot`, in any case

Comment: @sapi contary to my snap answer, I don't think that should matter, `plt.xlim` will call `plt.gca()` which will make a current axes if one does not exist.  That same axes will then be picked up by `plot` and work fine (just tested this).

Comment: @Krishnan, that is not the exact same code. One is `.set_xlim` the other is `.xlim`.

Comment: p.xlim (and p.ylim) do not seem to work (even after I called them after p.plot ... (something is not quite right ... could be something else I am not able to see) in the function, I need to do a reboot (!)

Answer (score 7):

You are setting `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` instead of calling it. Where you have:

```
p.set_xlim = ([0.0,10.0])
p.set_ylim = ([0.0,10.0])
```

you should have:

```
p.set_xlim([0.0,10.0])
p.set_ylim([0.0,10.0])
```

When you make that change, you'll notice that `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` can't be called because they don't exist in the `pylab` namespace. `pylab.xlim` is a shortcut that gets the current axes object and calls that object's `set_xlim` method. You could do this yourself with:

```
ax = p.subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim([0.0,10.0])
ax.set_ylim([0.0,10.0])
```

Comment: Thanks very much ... I have been staring at the code for a while and could NOT see that elementary error ... I sure appreciate your help, thanks again ... (as a cartoon character says "duh" of myself!)

Comment: No problem :) Staring at the same code too long puts on the familiarity blinders; it takes a new set of eyes to see these things!

Comment: I am trying to post something else about linregress and polyfit and just cannot seem to be able to get past the "censor" ... oh well - I did have the code properly set (so I thought) - and I did have comments on what the problem was - gave up after 10 attempts!